# Проблема в работе файла Pipfile и библиотеке urllib

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

При попытке создать миграции в проекте Django появляется такая вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProjects\Django\coomo-website\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\PythonProjects\Django\coomo-website\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Mysti\.virtualenvs\coomo-website-S_FagKfe\lib\site-packages\corsheaders\checks.py", line 88, in check_settings
    parsed = urlparse(origin)
  File "c:\users\mysti\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 390, in urlparse
    splitresult = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "c:\users\mysti\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 476, in urlsplit
    raise ValueError("Invalid IPv6 URL")
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
```

Вот сам файл Pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"
```

Comment: А почему вы решили, что Pipfile имеет какое-то отношение к этому? Текст ошибки намекает, что вы ошиблись в настройке CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS

Comment: Хмм.. Не знаю. Когда искал информацию по ошибке везде была проблема именно в ссылке пифайла

Comment: @andreymal Странно, сделал поиск по всему в проекте CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS эту строчку нигде не нашло.

Comment: Тогда может быть CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST

Comment: @andreymal `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'http://localhost:3000', '127.0.0.1'] + os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS').split(',')

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST.append('http://' + os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS'))` Вот, может здесь что-то не так.

Comment: `'http://' + os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS')` — ну вот видимо в переменной окружения ALLOWED_HOSTS написано нечто, что проекту не нравится (или просто ничего не написано)

Comment: Я кажется понял, http:// во втором случае лишнее @andreymal

Comment: @andreymal Нет, я был не прав. Все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @andreymal Я смог решить эту проблему вроде.